# How to make an if loop that loops something until a key is pressed

Tags: c#

I need to make a loop that loops some console.writeline stuff and does that until the user starts using the keyboard to console.readline(), and enter their own text. So, loop until user types.
Thanks

Comment: You will want to put a lot more effort into your posts in the future.  Visit the [HELP] and study [ask]

Comment: Probably not using `Console.ReadLine()`.  Not unless you use multiple THREADS.  Instead, you could use a loop w/ [Console.KeyAvailable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?view=netcore-3.1) and [Console.ReadKey(false)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_ReadKey_System_Boolean_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean by "loops some console.writeline stuff", but you can use a `while` loop to write something to the console every x seconds (.5 seconds in the example), and we can use `Console.KeyAvailable` in the condition, which returns true after the user presses a key:

```
while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
{
    Console.Write(".");
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Here's one example that displays a "waiting" indicator until the user enters some information:

```
public static string WaitAndGetUserInput()
{
    var chars = new[] {'-', '\\', '|', '/'};
    var index = 0;
    var left = Console.CursorLeft;
    var top = Console.CursorTop;

    Console.CursorVisible = false;

    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
        Console.Write(chars[index++ % chars.Length]);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey(true);

    Console.CursorVisible = true;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);

    if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        Console.Write(' ');
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(keyPressed.KeyChar);
    }

    return keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter
        ? ""
        : keyPressed.KeyChar + WaitAndGetUserInput();
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");

    // Display a wait indicator until user enters their name
    var userName = WaitAndGetUserInput();

    Console.WriteLine($"Welcome, {userName}!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

In the comments you mentioned that you want to flash a `':'` after some prompt, and the get user input after that. In order to do this, we can change the code to capture both the `':'` position and the cursor position for the user input. By doing this, we can move the cursor to the colon when we need to flash it, and then move it back to the user input location right away.

I also changed it so that it takes in a prompt to display before the user input, and it flashes the last character of that prompt:

```
public static string FlashLastCharAndGetUserInput(string prompt)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prompt)) return Console.ReadLine();

    var flash = 0;
    var chr = prompt.Last();
    // If the last char is   a ' ', flash it with a solid block
    if (chr == ' ') chr = '▓';
    var showChr = false;
    var userInput = new StringBuilder();

    Console.CursorVisible = false;
    Console.Write(prompt);

    var colonLeft = Console.CursorLeft - 1;
    var colonTop = Console.CursorTop;
    var cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft + 1;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    while (true)
    {
        if (++flash % 10000 == 0)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(colonLeft, colonTop);
            Console.Write($"{(showChr ? chr : ' ')} ");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
            showChr = !showChr;
            flash = 0;
        }

        if (!Console.KeyAvailable) continue;

        var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();
        if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) break;

        cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
        cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

        if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && userInput.Length > 0)
        {
            userInput.Remove(userInput.Length - 1, 1);
            Console.Write(' ');
            Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
        }
        else
        {
            userInput.Append(keyPressed.KeyChar);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    return userInput.ToString();
}
```

In use it would look something like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var name = FlashLastCharAndGetUserInput("Enter your name:");
    Console.WriteLine($"Welcome, {name}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: `KeyAvailable` is a property, not a function. .NET Core anyways

Comment: Wait so the whole reason I want this was so that I could add a flashing ":" after some text, where you would write, but when I try that it types to the left of the loading flashing not the right. Do you know how I could fix this? So that it types to the right of it. Also It is a bit weird when you backspace.

Comment: You could capture the current `Console.CursorPosition`, then use `Console.SetCursorPosition` to move it to the `:` location in the string, alternately write a `' '` or a `':'` there, then move the cursor back to it's original location to write input if it was received.

Comment: You can easily add code to handle backspace character as another `else if` after the `if` statement: `else if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)`

Comment: I updated the answer with a sample that does both of those things which may be helpful.